# Find duplicate values in Semantic MediaWiki

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

How would I go about to list any duplicate values for a property in Semantic MediaWiki? A MySQL query would do fine, it doesn't have to be through a SMW query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way that works for me:

With [Extension:Variables](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aVariables) installed, create a template `{{Detect duplicates}}` like this:

```
{{#ifeq:{{#var:a}}|{{#vardefineecho:a|{{{2|}}}}}|<!--

    Found a duplicate! Print some message:

-->Duplicate found: {{{2}}}<!--

    Not a duplicate, do nothing

-->|}}
```

and ask for values like this:

```
{{#ask:[[MyProperty::+]]
 |?MyProperty
 |sort=MyProperty
 |format=template
 |template=Detect duplicates
}}
```

It is important to sort the results before sending them to the template, as the duplicate has to come next to each others.